# Creating expandable list to show rest of content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a sidebar on my site that displays categories in this format.

```
Category1
Category2
Category3
Category4
Category5
```

However I have around 50 that I need to display. Instead of having my sidebar stretch very far down and look out of place I was wanting to display the top 10 and then provide a button that allows the sidebar to expand to show the rest. So on default it shows 10 but if the button is clicked it will expand and I will be able to see all 50. I am almost certain this will use some jQuery however I don't know where to start with this.

Here is the function that gets the categories from the database.

```
function load_categories()
{
global $db;

$query = $db->write_query('
    SELECT c.*, COUNT(n.id) AS count
    FROM ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'newscategories c
    LEFT JOIN ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'news n ON FIND_IN_SET (c.cid, n.cid)
    GROUP BY c.cid
    ORDER BY count DESC
    ');
while ($cat = $db->fetch_array($query)) {

    $categories[$cat['cid']] = array(
        'name' => $cat['name'],
        'count' => $cat['count']
       );

}

return $categories;
}
```

Here is the bit of PHP code that will output the categories each on a new line.

```
if ($all_categories) {
 foreach ($all_categories as $cid => $arr) {

   $sidebar .= '<a href="index.php?action=sort&cid=' . $cid . '">' . $arr['name'] . ' (' . $arr['count'] . ')</a><br />';

  }
} else {
  $sidebar = 'There are no categories yet';
}
```

Comment: You could always display the first 10 and then put the rest in a div with a style of dispaly: none. Then you could attach to the onclick event of the button to show that hidden div.

Comment: I am pretty new to web design, is there some sort of tutorial that will help me?

Comment: You could start at http://learn.jquery.com/ to learn more about jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will solve your purpose. I have created **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2v39N/)** for you requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#mysidebar{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 150px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $('#mysidebar').css('height','100%');

    });

});
</script>
<body>
<div id="mysidebar">
    <p>category1</p>
    <p>category2</p>
    <p>category3</p>
    <p>category4</p>
    <p>category5</p>
    <p>category6</p>
    <p>category7</p>
    <p>category8</p>
    <p>category9</p>
    <p>category10</p>
    <p>category1</p>
    <p>category2</p>
    <p>category3</p>
    <p>category4</p>
    <p>category5</p>
    <p>category6</p>
    <p>category7</p>
    <p>category8</p>
    <p>category9</p>
    <p>category10</p>
    <p>category1</p>
    <p>category2</p>
    <p>category3</p>
    <p>category4</p>
    <p>category5</p>
    <p>category6</p>
    <p>category7</p>
    <p>category8</p>
    <p>category9</p>
    <p>category10</p>

</div>
<div>
    <button id="mybutton">click here to expand it</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After doing some more tinkering and reading I came to a stop. My PHP function just displays all the categories it has. So I need to somehow take note that once It has displayed 10 categories to then hide the others. I don't manually enter the categories onto the list, they are generated from a foreach loop from the database. I will update my first post with the PHP code.

Comment: There is one more way. Once you reach 10 category, you can create a div with some id/class, and initially with display:none styling, then on clicking button, change new div style to display:block;

Comment: Would I use jQuery to detect if there is 10 categories?

Comment: I guess PHP for loop should be identifier for number of loops and then  if it reaches 10, then you need to insert JS/JQuery in php to create div element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple implementation of your requirement :

http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/3dyuC/1/

Approach :

Categories divided into 2 divs.(10,40) and a button to toggle display of the div with 40 elements.

```
$("#showAll").click(function () {
    $("#next40").slideDown(500);
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#next40").slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#showAll").show();
    });

});
```

**Further refs :**'

1. http://api.jquery.com/click/
2. http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/
3. http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ and http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/